# What is "Unexpected interface name" in objective c, iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I was using a class, MapMultiController, which extends UIViewController, and is instantiated from inside my ListViewController, which also extends UIViewController, like so:

```
@interface MapMultiController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate> {
    MKMapView           *mapView;
    UISegmentedControl  *barStyleSegControl;
    bool                wasUpdated;
}
```

and then this:

```
MapMultiController *controller = [[MapMultiController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapMultiController" bundle:nil];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

This all worked before, but then I commented out the allocation and all that from my ListViewController, and did some other things, and now when I'm trying to put it back in, it says "Unexpected interface name 'MapMultiController'", and of course everything after that doesn't work.

But everything looks correct to me! What's wrong?

Comment: What does the rest of MapMultiController.h look like (specifically the bits before the code in your question) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What probably happened is that in the course of your editing, you added some code before that @interface and now the compiler isn't expecting it where it's finding it.  It's not that your code is wrong, but that it's in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, I found it, and you're correct. In my case, I changed an if-else statement to a switch statement, and got the syntax wrong. When I added braces around the cases, the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

This error usually happens when you create an object where object creation is simply **not allowed**.

This very same error happened to me when I was allocating an object inside a `switch` statement:

```
switch (myInt) {
    case 1:
        NSString *string = @"Hello Exception!";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Yields following error:

> Semantic Issue: Unexpected interface name 'NSString': expected expression

Comment: Thanks, I found it, and you're correct. In my case, I changed an if-else statement to a switch statement, and got the syntax wrong. When I added braces around the cases, the error went away.

Comment: Great to hear your problem is gone. Don't forget to accept the answers that helped you.

Comment: You don't need to switch to an if-else statement. As you said, you can use curly brackets in both if-else and case constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Shaharyar isn't strictly correct, you can alloc and create objects from within a switch statement as-long as you enclose each case with curly brackets.

The following is valid use of the switch statement:

```
switch (myInt) {
    case 1:
    {
        NSString *string = @"Hello Exception!";
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```